# Rails 4 Dynamically Generate an Extra Public-Facing URL on Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a Rails app that stores stock photos in each project. Upon creating a project, I want the app to not only create the url for the project that we will view internally, which is `projects#show`,i.e. `/projects/4` but I also want it to create another URL that we can show to the client that will be a little different. It will allow the to approve the photos, etc. I want the url to be something like `/projects/st53d` where the end of the url will be a random number generated with `random_string = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5)`

This way, I can pass this url to the clients and they can view all the photos in the project and approve the ones they want us to use, but cannot change or view the other internal stuff we have on the standard product show page

Currently, I have added a `client_url` column to the `Project` model and I was thinking of generating the random number within the `Project#create` method and then saving it to the project's `client_url` column. This way I can loop through all client urls and make sure I did not generate a duplicate. But I cannot figure out how to do the route creation part.

i have yet to do the part where I check if it is random but I know how to do that, just not the route creation.

I was thinking I needed to create a new method which I named `show_client` and somehow create a route for that in my `config/routes.rb` file

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show,:index]

def create 
    @project = Project.create(project_params)
    @project.creator = current_user.email

    require 'securerandom'
    random_string = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5)
    @project.client_url = random_string
    @project.save

    redirect_to @project
end

def show_client
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @photos  = @project.photos
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like more of a roles issue. You could check out something like CanCanCan. If you only need two kinds of users, you could also just add a boolean column for admin to your user table. The url extension doesn't seem to matter in the scope of your problem. If you want to use a different view for the visiting the user show page, something in the show action like:

```
unless current_user.admin?
  redirect_to client_show(current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: Clients are not going to be logging in or anything like that. Not sure if we can give them a role without them creating an account which is not possible. It is technically possible, but the bosses do not want that.

Comment: The login we are having is google OAuth and it is restricted to one specific domain email address

Comment: if there's no auth for anyone and pages are editable...what would stop them from changing any page they choose?

Comment: There is auth for people with our specific work email through google. Without that log in, nobody can view any page except for the home page. I use devise and omniauth-google-2

Comment: I was able to figure it out and posted the answer in case you were curious.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.
I created the `client_url` column in the database and upon creating a project, in the `create` method of the `projects_controller`, I generated a random base64 number and assigned it to `project.client_url`

in `routes.rb` i did:

```
get 'projects/clients/:client_id' => 'projects#clients', as: 'projects_client'
```

in my `projects_controller.rb`:

```
def clients
    @project = Project.where(client_id: params[:client_id])
end
```

then the link to that route is:

```
<%= link_to 'Client Version', projects_client_path(@project.client_url)  %>
```